# Scaling background image to different window sizes? [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, background, scale

I'm currently trying to have a background image scale down to fit into different window sizes. The image I'm using is 1080x1920 and I'm trying to have it scale down to a window that is 540x960 in the code below. I'm not having any luck. I'm using bg.draw(g) below to draw the background and, in the past, was able to write "(g, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);" or something similar to have it scale, but it doesn't seem to be working out with this method.

Any help would be awesome!

GameState Class:

```
package GameState;

import SpriteSheet.Background;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MenuState extends GameState {

private Background bg;

private int currentChoice = 0;
private String[] options = {
    "Start",
    "Help",
    "Quit"
};

private Color titleColor;
private Font titleFont;

private Font font;

public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {

    this.gsm = gsm;

    try {

        bg = new Background("/Images/LivingRoom.png", 0.5);

        titleColor = new Color(128, 0, 0);
        titleFont = new Font(
                "Century Gothic",
                Font.PLAIN,
                28);

        font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void init() {}

public void update() {
    bg.update();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    // draw bg
    bg.draw(g);
    bg.resize(540, 960);

    // draw title
    g.setColor(titleColor);
    g.setFont(titleFont);
    g.drawString("Title", 80, 70);

    // draw menu options
    g.setFont(font);
    for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if(i == currentChoice) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }else {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        g.drawString(options[i], 145, 140 + i * 15);
    }

}

public void resize(){

    bg.resize(540, 960);

}

private void select() {
    if(currentChoice == 0) {
        // start
    }
    if(currentChoice == 1) {
        // help
    }
    if(currentChoice == 2) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void keyPressed(int k) {
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        select();
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        currentChoice--;
        if(currentChoice == -1) {
            currentChoice = options.length - 1;
        }
    }
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        currentChoice++;
        if(currentChoice == options.length) {
            currentChoice = 0;
        }
    }
}
public void keyReleased(int k) {}

public void draw() {}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

public void mouseClicked() {}

}
```

Background Class:

```
package SpriteSheet;

import Main.GamePanel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Background {

private static BufferedImage image;

private double x;
private double y;
private double dx;
private double dy;

private double moveScale;

public Background(String s, double ms) {

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream(s)
        );
        moveScale = ms;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
    this.x = (x * moveScale) % GamePanel.WIDTH;
    this.y = (y * moveScale) % GamePanel.HEIGHT;
}

public void setVector(double dx, double dy) {
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
}

public void update() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public void resize(int newWidth, int newHeight){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, image.getType());
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
    g.dispose();

    BufferedImage resizeImage = null;
    image = resizeImage;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);

    if(x < 0) {
        g.drawImage(
            image,
            (int)x + GamePanel.WIDTH,
            (int)y,
            null
        );
    }
    if(x > 0) {
        g.drawImage(
            image,
            (int)x - GamePanel.WIDTH,
            (int)y,
            null
        );
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is `Background` a custom class?

Comment: It is, sorry! I added an edit with the background class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to resize a `BufferedImage`

You can add this as a `resize()` method to the `Background` class where the variable `image` is your `Background` class's instance `image` variable:

```
private void resize(int newWidth, int newHeight){
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, image.getType());
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
    g.dispose();

    image = resizeImage;
}
```

Then you can call this resize method as `bg.resize(int x, int y)` in the `MenuState` class